# Check if value matches any of the other values in array in JS ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, include

I have tried a few things. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

I have a form where the user needs to put in all the people who are attending:

**Person 1**
Name
DOB
Email

**Person 2**
Name
DOB
Email

etc

I need to work out if any of the "Email" values are the same.

So I orginally thought get all the inputs:

`let checkEmails = document.querySelectorAll("[data-email='email']");`

and when each of those is updated run a function to check and pass the value:

```
for (const inputs of Array.from(checkEmails)) {
    inputs.onchange = function(){
        const value = this.value;
        checkMatchingEmails(value);
    };
}
```

First I tried using the "includes" method, but it was always returning "doesn't match", wasn't sure how to debug that so I tried different methods.

```
function checkMatchingEmails(value){

    if (Array.from(checkEmails).includes(({ value }) == value)) {
        console.log("matches");
    } else {
        console.log("doesnt match");
    }
}
checkMatchingEmails();
```

If you can see my issue here please stop reading as I just mention other methods I tried:

Another method:

```
function checkMatchingEmails(value){

    let checkEmailValues = document.querySelectorAll("[data-pnr-field='passportNumber'].value");

    for (const inputValues of Array.from(checkEmailValues)) {

        if(inputValues == value) {
            console.log("matches");
        } else {
            console.log("doesnt match");
        }
    }

}
checkMatchingEmails();
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
let checkEmails = [];

const checkEmailValues = document.querySelectorAll("[data-pnr-field='passportNumber']");

checkEmailValues.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('change', checkMatchingEmailValues));

function checkMatchingEmailValues(e) {
    const email = e.target.value;
    if(checkEmails.includes(email)){
        console.log("email matches");
        console.log(e);
    } else {
        console.log("email doesnt match");
        checkEmails.push(email);
    }
    console.log(checkEmails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

**Mistake 1**

`document.querySelectorAll("[data-email='email']")`
returns a `NodeList`.

You cannot check if it `includes` a `string` value and will always return `false`.

You should check the documentation on  [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

**Mistake 2**

```
inputs.onchange = function(){
```

This is not how we add event listeners.

Use `inputs.addEventListener("change", function)`

Refer the documentation here  [Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

**Possible solution**

You should basically create an `Array` of string values and do an `includes` on the same. Also you might need to track the index of each element.

A rough implementation might look like below. You can run the snippet and see the validation errors.

```js
let checkEmails = document.querySelectorAll("[data-email='email']");
let emailsEntered = [];
for (let i = 0; i < checkEmails.length; i++) {
  checkEmails[i].addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (!checkMatchingEmails(value)) {
      emailsEntered[i] = value;
      e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML =
        `This value is already entered at index ${emailsEntered.indexOf(value)}`
    }
    console.log(emailsEntered);
  });
}

function checkMatchingEmails(value) {
  return emailsEntered.includes(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" data-email="email" />
<div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" data-email="email" />
<div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" data-email="email" />
<div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" data-email="email" />
<div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
```

**Please note that this is just a rough draft and not all the edge cases might be handled.**